# SQL Error in query for "undefined" column (?)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   SELECT Output.name, Output.avgSalary 
   FROM (SELECT Airplane.aid, Airplane.aname AS name, 
                AVG (worker.salary) AS avgSalary 
         FROM Aircraft Airplane , Certified IsCertified, Employees worker 
         WHERE Airplane.aid = IsCertified.aid AND 
               IsCertified.eid = worker.eid AND 
               Airplane.crusingrange >  1000 
          GROUP BY Airplane.aid, Airplane.aname) AS Output
```

Oracle SQL says error at "AS Output" near the end, yet I cannot figure out what is wrong with it. :S

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
         SELECT Airplane.aid, Airplane.aname AS name, 
                AVG (worker.salary) AS avgSalary 
         FROM Aircraft Airplane INNER JOIN Certified IsCertified on
                   Airplane.aid = IsCertified.aid 
              INNER JOIN Employees worker on IsCertified.eid = worker.eid
         WHERE Airplane.crusingrange >  1000 
          GROUP BY Airplane.aid, Airplane.aname
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a subselect. This query is equivalent:

```
SELECT
    Airplane.aname AS name, 
    AVG(worker.salary) AS avgSalary 
FROM Aircraft Airplane
JOIN Certified IsCertified ON Airplane.aid = IsCertified.aid
JOIN Employees worker ON IsCertified.eid = worker.eid
WHERE Airplane.crusingrange > 1000 
GROUP BY Airplane.aid, Airplane.aname
```